# Calculate z_score for a column grouped by another column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, statistics

Suppose I have a DataFrame with columns `person_id` and `mean_act`, where every row is a numerical value for a specific person. I want to calculate the zscore for all the values at a person level. That is, I want a new column `mean_act_person_zscore` that is computed as the zscore of `mean_act` using the mean and std of the zscores for that person only (and not the whole dataset).

My first approach is something like this:

```
person_ids = df['person_id'].unique()
for pid in person_ids:
    person_df = df[df['person_id'] == pid]
    person_df = (person_df['mean_act'] - person_df['mean_act'].mean())/person_df['mean_act'].std()
```

At every iteration, it computes the right zscore output series, but the problem is that since the selection is by reference, not by value, the original `df` ends up without having the `mean_act_person_zscore` column.

Thoughts as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be straight forward:

```
df['mean_act_person_zscore'] = df.groupby('person_id').mean_act.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```

Comment: That did it. Wasn't familiar with pandas groupby transforms, and docs aren't really there.